# How to convert a list of numbers to a list of letters, Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

New to python and I'm trying to code a encrypted message

The alphabet has been rewritten as follows:

```
cipher = [ "q", "a", "z", "w", "s", "x", "e", "d", "c", "r", "f", "v", "t", "g", "b", "y", "h", "n", "u", "j", "m", "i", "k", "o", "l", "p"]

idx = ord ("d") - ord ("a")

print(cipher[3])
```

OUTPUT:
w

```
input = str(input('Write Text: ')) #hello world used here
input = input.lower()
output = []
for character in input:
    number = ord(character) - 97
    output.append(number)
print(output)
```

OUTPUT:

[7, 4, 11, 11, 14, -65, 22, 14, 17, 11, 3]

Not sure how to correspond these two...

I've tried:

```
print(cipher[output])
```

Returns a TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list

Thanks in advance

Comment: first of all, you need to account for spaces - right now it results in that nasty `-65`, which will break everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like:

```
deciphered = [cipher[i] if i > 0 else ' ' for i in output]
print(''.join(deciphered))
```

note the `i>0` bit is in there to handle spaces, which result in a `number` of -65...